# How to bubble up keyboard events from winform hosted control

Tags: wpf, winforms

I have an interop scenario where a winform textbox is hosted within a WPF window. I'm using the windows inputbindings in order to relay commands to backend components. This is working pretty well except for commands that use the arrow keys such as Up,Down,Left,Right. When these are ran they seem to get handled by the textbox and not getting bubbled up to the main window. Is there a way to manually bubble up the keyboard command or a setting on the textbox that I could set?

To duplicate create a window with a windowformhost component and add an inputbinding. Other keygestures are handled but not any that use the arrow keys.

```
<Window>
    <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="Tb">

    </WindowsFormsHost>
</Window>

public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.InputBindings.Add(new InputBinding(new DelegateCommand(() =>
        {
            var s = '0';
        }), new KeyGesture(Key.Up, ModifierKeys.Control)));
        Tb.Child = new TextBox();

    }
```

Thanks

Comment: There is not a WPF control that does what you need?

Comment: I've found the same behavior with wpf textboxes as well. They seem to handle the arrow commands so they don't get bubbled up. Is there a way of bubbling keyboard gestures that use the arrow keys?

Comment: PreviewKeyDown event does get bubble arrow